# Updating User Specific Data from Winforms app using a Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, session

There is a desktop application that communicates with a WebService. The application sends counter increment request for a specific user to a web service.
I plan to implement user authentication in the desktop application as it uses web service resources allotted to a specific user. The code below simply calls an `Setter` method to Set the `counter` value in the database.Passing Username and Password hash each time through a `webmethod` seems inefficient.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem? Perhaps using Sessions?

```
[WebMethod]
public void setter(int value)
{
   c.Open();
   String x = null;
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE newtable SET counter=@cvalue WHERE uname=@username", c);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "me");
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cvalue",value);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't not raise the fact that your increment method doesn't increment, it sets.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Yes... Its just a sample mockup code.

Comment: Fair enough. What's inefficient about sending username/password? You could use token auth instead? What's the requirement?

Comment: @ChrisPickford Sending Username and Password each time will be a security risk.Also maintaining some kind of session seems more efficient IMO.Could you please guide me to some token authentication examples.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Edited the question to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Security risk how? You said you are hashing the pw. Do a search for OAuth. It's hard to help without knowing what you're trying to accomplish. "Better approach" and "more efficient" aren't quantifiable.

Comment: @ChrisPickford So,if you were to implement something like this,you would send username and hashed password?

Comment: If you need that counter permanently, it would be better to save it in Persist memory like Database, but if you want there are another ways to do that such a `List`, Session is not good approach and accessible in desktop application.

Comment: @Aria I just need to check the counter before sending requests and increment it after the request is sent.On behalf of the logged in user.

Comment: What is the purpose of counting requests? if you establish token based authentication in server side there is no need to limit request count.

Comment: @Aria I need to limit resource available to a user.

Comment: @techno, If you mean RLS, there are another ways to implement Resource base-authorization, anyway if you want to limit user requests, there is security risk to pass u/p in each request, I highly recommend you to pass security token JWT the validate and retrieve username from it then check counter for that user in DB. if this question is about resource authorization and limitation it should be implement in server side (here in your service) like you mentioned in question, better way is storing counter in DB but if that counter should be check per session it is better to use session in your api.